# No Internet connection after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

I've just upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1, but after upgrading I can't connect to the Internet. I select my Wi-Fi network and click "Connect". Even though it says it's connected, I cannot open any page and the troubleshoot helper says that I'm not connected to any network.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your WiFi protected with a password? Did you enter it correctly?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Yes, I've entered it correctly. Windows says it's connected.

Comment: Can you ping the gateway? e.g. ping 192.168.1.1

Comment: Good to see this question and answer solve a few issues others had, original thought it was a specific configuration I had when experienced this that was a virtual Wifi-bridge with the problem until I spotted these options were changed!

Comment: I have a similar issue. Pls see http://superuser.com/questions/1023244/windows-10-wifi-connection-drops-throughput-issue

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure the IPv4 and IPv6 protocols are enabled:

- Go to Advanced Network settings
- Go to Network and Sharing Centre
- Go to Change Adapter Settings

  [image: Network]
- Select Properties for the Wifi Adapter (right-click your connection):

  [image]
- Make sure the IPv4 and IPv6 protocols are selected

  [image]

I also couldn't connect to internet after upgrading and found that these had been disabled. Once enabled you should be able to connect.

Comment: That solved it! Thank you. 

Not sure why Windows disabled all of those during upgrade, must be some sort of bug.

Comment: Great glad that worked - I had no idea why it did that it was seemly connected fine but getting no internet, was very strange until I checked this!

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid all these options are enabled on my HP EliteBook 840 G2 running Win 10 (21H2 OS Build 19044.1415) with Intel Dual Band Wireless-N 7265 WiFi card but still it is not able to connect to the SSID on TP-Link Archer C80 AC1900 router but it connects to the SSIS on Netgear R6220 AC1200.

Answer (score 3):

After sleepless weekend got rid of this problem. It is Bitdefender TS in my case. Uninstalled it and Internet came back in a flash. Also updated all drivers for my Mobo Gigabyte D3H B85M from official site to Windows 10. Re-install latest version of Bitdefender TS. All fine now. Thank God.

Comment: So you updated *all* your drivers, and you still argue that it's Bitdefender TS (a.k.a. "total security") that was the culprit? You should have had a look at the answer above before you updated the drivers. It might have saved you at least one good night's sleep. Because when you re-installed drivers, one or several of your network devices may have become enabled (if they were previously disabled).

Comment: I know I'm a bit late, but I just wanted to say thanks, this solution did work for me (I was also connected but with no internet). My problem was the Comodo firewall; right after I uninstalled and restarted, the internet was working fine.

Comment: It was ESET for me. Looks like anti-virus/firewall programs can have compatibility issues.

Comment: For me it was Avast!  It is recommended to remove anti-virus of all types as one of the steps to trouble shoot this.  I didn't do anything with the drivers; I just read a bunch and picked the least harmful, easiest solution first (after ipconfig, other simple trouble shooting steps).