# Windows 10 Wifi can't connect

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, wifi-driver

This seems to be a common problem on some of the Win 10 running PC's.

**Overview** 
After upgrading to Windows 10 through a clean install, I was using my Asus x200 ma (a netbook probably made for surfing Internet) for surfing the Internet through wifi and everything was working fine. Recently, probably 3 months later, the Wifi can't detect any network. It sometimes detect networks but it instantly turns to No available connection. Sometimes, I was fast enough to click on the connect button and then enter the pass key. But a while later, a message showing 'Can't connect to this network' always appears. I've searched on Internet and stack exchange sites but nothing worked. 
I found [this](https://superuser.com/q/1003835/403640) question useful as it had a variety of answers but it neither worked.

**Screenshots**:
[image: No available networks]

[image: My Wifi properties]

[image: Wifi adapter details]

As I told before, I am running Asus x200 ma windows 10.

**Things I have tried**

- Googling a lot about the problem.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling WLAN drivers.
- Executing a few commands like the one that deletes some registry values. I don't remember all of them. But it resulted in 'Error: no such value found'.

Please help and if needed comment for further details.

Update: A few commands that I've executed for solving the problem :-

- reg delete HKCR\CLSID{988248f3-
  a1ad-49bf-9170-676cbbc36ba3} /va /f
- netsh int ip reset
- netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled
  netsh int tcp set global
  autotuninglevel=disabled
  netsh int tcp set global rss=enabled
  netsh int tcp show global

Comment: **This seems to be a common problem on all Win 10 running PC's.** - This statement is false, it does not happen to **ALL** Windows 10   machines.  You should edit your question, to include the commands, you attempted to run in order to modify the registry.

Comment: The following [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/qualcomm-atheros-ar956x-wireless-network-adapter/cfa052b4-db43-4b3d-a4f1-e39dabbe158c) as some important diagnostic steps you should take.  Update your question and include the results of those steps.

Comment: @Ramhound I've updated my question with further details. As I've mentioned before,  I don't remember all of the commands that I executed. The ones that I remember have been given.

Comment: You failed to address the diagnostic steps.

Comment: @Ramhound  That article suggested me to go to safe mode and check the problem. Yes, the problem persists. And if talking about the clean boot, it was a bit tricky, so I found that method a bit unsafe. Then I headed to the automated troubleshooter. That gave me an advice to turn my router off for a bit and then turn it on. This method, as expected, had nothing to do with my PC's wifi. Any other method?

Comment: A clean boot can be acomplished safely by just using AutoRuns to manually configure what is started with the profile.  What exactly is tricky about doing a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135) though?  The link still applies to Windows 10 by the way.  Either way you decide to try this, be sure, the driver you need is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Many older WiFi-chipsets seem to have faulty/buggy drivers for Windows 10. Often you're better off trying to find the Windows 8 driver and using specifically that one with Windows 10. I have encountered this problem on several computers with different WiFi hardware, that I upgraded to Windows 10.

But as an immediate fix, what always helped for me:

- Go to "Network Connections" (you have it open in your 2nd screenshot)
- Right-click the wifi adapter and click "Disable", wait a few seconds
- Right-click the disabled wifi adapter and click "Enable"

This always worked for me. Though annoying, it is much less annoying than having to restart the whole computer.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't worked. I tried disabling it and then enabling it again. The name appears for about 5-6 seconds then suddenly disappears.

Comment: I am sorry it didn't help you. Did you try downloading the latest driver from ASUS website? If you say it worked for a couple of month with Windows 10, maybe a neighbor installed a new wifi which is now interfering with your signal?

Comment: I think so because sometimes I get another Wifi signal for much time but didn't catch my desired Wifi. If talking about drivers, Asus haven't updated yet. So any other method?

Comment: You could try using different driver versions and maybe you will find one that works. Or it might be possible to exchange the wifi card for one that is specifically working with windows 10.

Comment: I think I've found a workaround. I've enabled something called Adhoc11 from my adapter's setting. And it worked. I don't think that it'll always work because I've tried this before with a failure. It wasn't working that time. So I can't say that its an answer. The question is still open for a reasonable answer.

Comment: If you could post it here as an answer, that would be helpful as I'm having similar problems with my generic windows tablet. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidWilson I can't as I told that it's a workaround. Well you can try this :- Click on Network settings from the bottom wifi button, then go to change adapter settings, then right click on your wifi and select properties. Head to configure as shown in screenshot 2 in the question. Now go to the advanced tab. There you'll see an option that reads Adhoc11 and enable it. Try it out if it works.