# Wifi: can't connect to this network

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I'm in a holiday home. With 4 phones and 3 laptops we can connect to the Wifi network, however, with my Windows 10 laptop I get "can't connect to this network". So I made one of my phones a hotspot and connected via the hotspot on my phone. So, yes, there is a workaround. ... However ... it bugs me why I can not connect.

- intel wireless-ac 9260 160Mhz - no newer drivers - 21.110.2.1
- windows troubleshooter nogo
- setting in the properties the "n" option to disabled did not help
- properties are set to auto get dns and ip
- tried all of this [Windows 10 Wi-Fi issue: "Can't connect to this network"](https://superuser.com/questions/1003835/windows-10-wi-fi-issue-cant-connect-to-this-network/1067841#1067841)
- event logs do not show anything specific

  ```
   Interface name: Wi-Fi

   Driver                    : Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9260 160MHz
   Vendor                    : Intel Corporation
   Provider                  : Intel
   Date                      : 7/21/2020
   Version                   : 21.110.2.1
   INF file                  : oem72.inf
   Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
   Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11g 802.11n 802.11a 802.11ac
   FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
   802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
   Hosted network supported  : No
   Authentication and cipher supported in infrastructure mode:
                            Open            None
                            Open            WEP-40bit
                            Open            WEP-104bit
                            Open            WEP
                            WPA-Enterprise  TKIP
                            WPA-Enterprise  CCMP
                            WPA-Personal    TKIP
                            WPA-Personal    CCMP
                            WPA2-Enterprise TKIP
                            WPA2-Enterprise CCMP
                            WPA2-Personal   TKIP
                            WPA2-Personal   CCMP
                            Open            Vendor defined
                            WPA3-Personal   CCMP
                            Vendor defined  Vendor defined
                            WPA3-Enterprise Unknown
                            Unknown         CCMP
   IHV service present       : Yes
   IHV adapter OUI           : [00 00 00], type: [00]
   IHV extensibility DLL path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\IntelIHVRouter08.dll
   IHV UI extensibility ClSID: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
   IHV diagnostics CLSID     : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
   Wireless Display Supported: Yes (Graphics Driver: Yes, Wi-Fi Driver: Yes)
  ```

The network I'm connecting to is pretty default:

```
  Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
  Cipher                 : TKIP
```

More

```
Wireless Device Capabilities
----------------------------

Interface name: Wi-Fi

WDI Version (Windows)                       : 0.1.1.8

WDI Version (IHV)                           : 0.1.1.9

Firmware Version                            : E2.4A

Station                                     : Supported

Soft AP                                     : Not supported

Network monitor mode                        : Not supported

Wi-Fi Direct Device                         : Supported

Wi-Fi Direct GO                             : Supported

Wi-Fi Direct Client                         : Supported

Protected Management Frames                 : Supported

DOT11k neighbor report                      : Supported

ANQP Service Information Discovery          : Supported

Action Frame                                : Supported

Diversity Antenna                           : Supported

IBSS                                        : Not Supported

Promiscuous Mode                            : Not Supported

P2P Device Discovery                        : Supported

P2P Service Name Discovery                  : Supported

P2P Service Info Discovery                  : Not Supported

P2P Background Discovery                    : Supported

P2P GO on 5 GHz                             : Supported

ASP 2.0 Service Name Discovery              : Not Supported

ASP 2.0 Service Information Discovery       : Not Supported

IP Docking Capable                          : Not Supported

FIPS                                        : Supported

Instant Connect                             : Supported

Dx Standby NLO                              : Supported

Extended Channel Switch Announcement        : Supported

Function Level Reset                        : Supported

Platform Level Reset                        : Supported

Bus Level Reset                             : Not Supported

MAC Randomization                           : Supported

Fast Transition                             : Supported

MU-MIMO                                     : Supported

Miracast Sink                               : Supported

BSS Transition (802.11v)                    : Supported

IHV Extensibility Module Configured         : Supported

SAE Authentication                          : Supported

FTM as Initiator                          : Not Supported

MBO Support                                 : Supported

Number of Tx Spatial Streams                : 2

Number of Rx Spatial Streams                : 2

Number of Concurrent Channels Supported     : 0

P2P GO ports count                          : 1

P2P Clients Port Count                      : 1

P2P Max Mobile AP Clients                   : 10

Max ANQP Service Advertisements Supported   : 0

Co-existence Support                        : Wi-Fi performance is maintained
```