# Cannot use the internet on Windows 10

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I have recently installed W10 on a desktop (brand new installation, there wasn't any OS installed before).

I use a USB wireless lan card to connect to my local network. Until a few days ago I could surf the internet on my desktop although it was painfully slow. Now I am no longer able to use the internet - it connects to the network, gets an IP, am able to ping the AP but the web pages don't load. In fact, I am able to ping the AP but I cannot access its admin page via any browser.

I am able to surf the internet when I plug the same USB wireless card on my laptop.

I've tried this [No internet connection after upgrade to Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947418/no-internet-connection-after-upgrade-to-windows-10) but it didn't work.

Any clue?

Comment: We need more information.  Simply saying it does not work is not enough to go by.

Comment: Reinstall the usb network adapter driver.

Comment: What other info do you consider relevant, Ramhound? Sorry am not an expert on OS and networks =)

Comment: It is a plug-and-play decide Moab - didn't find any specific driver to it. Anyway my laptop runs W10 as well and the card works fine.